# Input box vs input box text and placeholder opacity

Tags: html, css

I have a simple input box

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Account Name">
```

with the following styles:

```
input {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 564px;
    opacity: 0.14;
}
```

My problem is because I have changed the opacity of the input box, when typing any text inside the input box it follows that opacity (the text is unreadable due to the low opacity). Is there any way of targeting the opacity for the input box and the opacity for the input box text separate?

EXAMPLE:

[image: Link to this example]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the alpha channel (rgba) to apply an opaque background rather than opacity. In case someone was wondering how to style placeholder text, it looks like there's an experimental pseudo-element: `::placeholder`.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffd6ed;
}

input {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.14);
  color: #23a1fc;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="An example">
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with the text that is being typed inside the box?

Comment: I must have misread: were you trying to change the text color, not the placeholder? Can you help me understand why the opacity style is needed?

Comment: No worries at all! I appreciate the help! The opacity style is purely for aesthetic reasons, I have a gradient background so making the input box semi-transparent gives it a really cool effect.